# Connect to mongo from shell using .jks file

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I have a .jks certificate and I am trying to connect to mongo. I haven't found anything on the net that handles this issue. They all deal with .crt or .pem files.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
mongo --ssl --sslPEMKeyFile /location/certfile.jks host.example.com:27017,host.example.com:27017,host.example.com.com:27017/databasename -u username -p password
```

I get this error:

> E NETWORK  [main] cannot read certificate file: location/certfile.jks
>   error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
>   Failed global initialization: InvalidSSLConfiguration Can not set up PEM key file.

Can someone tell me what wrong I am doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the password of this .jks file.

Convert it to pem file using this tutorial:

> https://cinhtau.net/2016/08/09/convert-private-ssl-key-from-jks-to-pem-format/

During the process, it will ask to use openssl command. You can download it from:

> https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries

Now you have the pem file. So now issue this command in command prompt:

```
mongo --ssl hostname.example.com:portnumber,hostname.example.com:portnumber,hostname.example.com:portnumber/databasename -u username -p password --sslPEMKeyFile "C:\localtion\certificate.pem"
```